# Не постится картинка на стену ВК

Tags: php

```
private function Photo($src){
    $name = "/var/www/www-root/data/www/sat.ru/loadfiles/moduls/doska/smallfoto/d5eeb06e92530347844c74db2188c139.jpg";
    $ch = curl_init($this->getServer());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['photo' => new \CurlFile($name, 'image/jpeg', 'd5eeb06e92530347844c74db2188c139')]);
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    var_dump($response);

    return json_decode($response);
}
```

получаю на выходе

```
string(72) "{"server":840729,"photo":"[]","hash":"faf82b1faa72913f733b8b482f8bfe25"}"
```

В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 0):

Забыл указать расширение файла в имени. Так работает:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['photo' => new \CurlFile($name, 'image/jpeg', 'd5eeb06e92530347844c74db2188c139.jpg')]);
```